# What did Mikura see that are coming in the finale?

Tags: mezzo-dsa

Who are these characters that Mikura sees in her vision of the future at the end of *Mezzo DSA*?

[image: bunch of people]
[image: dark man with metal mask and sombrero hat]

My guess is that they're from an upcoming anime, but a quick Google reverse image search and a text search for anime by Yasuomi Umetsu or Arms Corporation, the director of and the studio behind *Mezzo DSA*, respectively, revealed nothing.